# Using HTML in Mandrill handlebar merge variables

Tags: php, mailchimp, mandrill

If I have a handlebar merge variable like `{{message}}` in my template, how can I have it render HTML output if given the following in PHP:

```
array(
    'name' => 'message',
    'content' => '<p>First paragraph.</p><p>Second paragraph.</p>'
)
```

Right now it outputs the content without parsing the paragraph tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, I just added `mc:edit="message"` to the div containing the message, like this:

`<div mc:edit="message"></div>`

I then added this to my structure:

```
$template_content = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'message',
        'content' => '<p>First paragraph.</p><p>Second paragraph.</p>'
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 14):

If you're using Handlebars I think the proper way to do it is with triple braces, e.g:

```
{{{html_content}}}
```

I'm not sure it is ok to mix mc:edit with Handlebars in Mandrill:

> Combining Handlebars with either mc:edit regions or merge tags in a single message isn't supported. You should pick Handlebars or mc:edit regions plus merge tags.

https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-dynamic-content

Answer (score 8):

Actually when sending using mandrill the message variable has a field merge_language and when you change to this

```
'merge_language' => 'handlebars'
```

It works. For your case i think the value is default 'mailchimp' hence the need to use mc:edit

Comment: This was the real problem. Thanks for that.

Comment: This should do it!

Comment: This just fixed my 1 hour search to get handlebars working, I would give you a 1000+ if I could. `merge_language: 'handlebars'` for me in node